# Trouble with enum constructor in Java

Tags: java, enums

I am unsure if the enum Family is in the correct position, however I get the same errors weather it is inside or outside my main class. These enums; WILMA, FRED, BETTY, & BARNEY will provide the 
data to calculate their retirement savings.

```
public class Assignment5
{

    enum Family
    {
        WILMA("Wilma", "Flintstone", 5000, 0.05, 10, 35),
        FRED("Fred", "Flintstone", 15000, 0.075, 7, 30), //fred might swap with betty 
        BETTY("Betty", "Rubble", 7500, 0.0375, 10, 25), 
        BARNEY("Barney", "Rubble", 5000, 0.09, 10, 35),
    }

        //The properties’ “getters”/accessors should go here.

        //instance fields
        private final String firstName; //first names
        private final String lastName; //last names
        private final int annualDeposit; //annual deposit
        private final double annualRate; //annual rate
        private final int yearsDeposit; //number of years depositing
        private final int yearsCalc; //number of years to compound

        //enum family constructor
        Assignment5(String firstName, String lastName, int annualDeposit, double annualRate, int   yearsDeposit, int yearsCalc)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.annualDeposit = annualDeposit;
            this.annualRate = annualRate;
            this.yearsDeposit = yearsDeposit;
            this.yearsCalc = yearsCalc;
        }

        //getter for firstName
        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        //getter for lastName
        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        //getter for annual deposit
        public int getAnnualDeposit()
        {
            return annualDeposit;
        }

        //getter for annual rate
        public double getAnnualRate()
        {
            return annualRate;
        }

        //getter for years deposit
        public int getYearsDeposit()
        {
            return yearsDeposit;
        }

        //getter for years calc
        public int getYearsCalc()
        {
            return yearsCalc;
        }

        //main method
        //formulas for calculating retirement account and printing results will go here
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        }

}
```

Comment: What is `Assignment5`? Shouldn't it be `Family` instead?

Comment: Doing that gives me an invalid method declaration, i've tried it before. Assignment5 is the name of my main class

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), and in particular scroll down to the `Planet` example.  Basically, some of the stuff you have outside the `enum`'s curly braces needs to be inside.

Answer (score 3):

To create an `enum` with parameters you should use a suitable constructor. In your case change your enum to this:

```
enum Family
{
    WILMA("Wilma", "Flintstone", 5000, 0.05, 10, 35),
    FRED("Fred", "Flintstone", 15000, 0.075, 7, 30), //fred might swap with betty 
    BETTY("Betty", "Rubble", 7500, 0.0375, 10, 25), 
    BARNEY("Barney", "Rubble", 5000, 0.09, 10, 35);
    //instance fields
    private final String firstName; //first names
    private final String lastName; //last names
    private final int annualDeposit; //annual deposit
    private final double annualRate; //annual rate
    private final int yearsDeposit; //number of years depositing
    private final int yearsCalc; //number of years to compound

    Family(String firstName, String lastName, int annualDeposit, double annualRate, int   yearsDeposit, int yearsCalc)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.annualDeposit = annualDeposit;
        this.annualRate = annualRate;
        this.yearsDeposit = yearsDeposit;
        this.yearsCalc = yearsCalc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should enum Family be inside my class or before it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like it would make more sense to define a class 'person' rather than an enum 'family'. Enums are better suited to define constants that belong in a cohesive package and may have values that are unlikely to change.

Therefore creating a class instance for each individual is more logical because you can design your program to interact with the class type rather than predefined constants. To keep things modular etc.

**Person class:**

```
public class Person {

    //instance fields
    private final String firstName; //first names
    private final String lastName; //last names
    private final int annualDeposit; //annual deposit
    private final double annualRate; //annual rate
    private final int yearsDeposit; //number of years depositing
    private final int yearsCalc; //number of years to compound

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int annualDeposit, double annualRate, int   yearsDeposit, int yearsCalc)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.annualDeposit = annualDeposit;
        this.annualRate = annualRate;
        this.yearsDeposit = yearsDeposit;
        this.yearsCalc = yearsCalc;
    }

    //getter for firstName
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    //getter for lastName
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    //getter for annual deposit
    public int getAnnualDeposit()
    {
        return annualDeposit;
    }

    //getter for annual rate
    public double getAnnualRate()
    {
        return annualRate;
    }

    //getter for years deposit
    public int getYearsDeposit()
    {
        return yearsDeposit;
    }

    //getter for years calc
    public int getYearsCalc()
    {
        return yearsCalc;
    }
}
```

Then in your main function you can directly declare a person and do your desired calculations etc., without the program needing to be hard-coded to interact with your enum structure.

**Main function:**

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person wilma = new Person("Wilma", "Flintstone", 5000, 0.05, 10, 35);
    }

}
```